# Magento Page Pagination Sort By Is Missing (Gone all of sudden)

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I don't see any more sort by (best match etc) or page numbers It's gone and I have no idea why or how I have checked all .xml files they are all correct it's not the issue. What can I check more to fix this?  Html files also seem fine I have reindex all nothing!

Comment: first remove cache from var/cache folder and then check the code on toolbar.phtml which is in the YOUR THEME/template/catalog/product/list/ folder...

Comment: Try to enable template hints and see if there is a block in the layout.

Comment: @Amasty thank you for this tip wasn't aware of this feature, I have just enabled my amasty (funny you're creator of it?) layered navigation and it got fixed...  (was disabled before maybe this caused it) I was looking to how to fold category + price filters but it's not possible? because price + category isn't located inside filters page.

Comment: Yes, I'm the author of the Improved Layered Navigation module :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have disabled layered navigation module in admin area.  It's not the real "disable", but disable of the module output.  All module blocks becomes "hidden".  The module rewrites the toolbar block with the sorter and pager, so it also has became invisible.

To restore the block display please enable modules output back.

If you have questions regarding the module, please contact us via support, as this site denies discussion of paid modules.